# How to rotate nginx logs for windows based on file file size

Tags: nginx, server

I am not able to configure log rotation in nginx.
I have installed nginx service on windows machine using windows service wrapper.
I have tried reopening log file using nginx -s reopen but command giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

Try following link
[Nginx loggging tips](https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/how-to-rotate-nginx-logs/#)

Comment: Thanks!, but I think this solution will work for centOS, I have configured nginx on windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx does not have any built in module for rolover logs on windows or any other platform, you can reopen nginx log if you are running nginx using nginx.exe but if you are running nginx using installed service you have to stop service then rotate logs and then start service again,

**Use below batch script to rotate nginx error logs and access logs on windows machine**

```
REM script to rotates nginx logs from java/windows cmd prompt

REM rolloverNginxLogs.bat [maxFileSize in bytes] [retainCount]
REM e.g rolloverNginxLogs.bat 10000 5

@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd C:\nginx\logs

set ERRORLEVEL=0
set maxFileSize=%1
set retainCount=%2
set errorLogFile=error.log
set accessLogFile=access.log

set rotateAccessLogFile=""
set rotateErrorLogFile=""
set rotateFile=""

REM set current time, replace " " with "0" for hours less than 10
set currentTime=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
if %currentTime% LSS 100000 (set currentTime=%currentTime: =0%)

REM check if access.log file rotation required
for %%A in (%accessLogFile%) do (
    echo.Size of "%%A" is %%~zA bytes
    if /I %%~zA GTR %maxFileSize% (
        set rotateAccessLogFile=true
        set rotateFile=true
    )
)

REM check if error.log file rotation required
for %%A in (%errorLogFile%) do (
    echo.Size of "%%A" is %%~zA bytes
    if /I %%~zA GTR %maxFileSize% (
        set rotateErrorLogFile=true
        set rotateFile=true
    )
)

REM if required rotate logs otherwise exit
if "%rotateFile%" EQU "true" (
    goto ROTATELOG
) else (
    goto DONE
)

:ROTATELOG 
REM check whether the service is running if running then stop service
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "nginx" ^| findstr "STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" EQU "RUNNING" (
   net stop "nginx"      
  )
)

REM rotate error log
if "%rotateErrorLogFile%" EQU "true" (
    ren error.log error-%DATE%-%currentTime%.log
    for /f "skip=%retainCount% eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d error*.log') do @del "%%F"
)

REM rotate access log
if "%rotateAccessLogFile%" EQU "true" (
    ren access.log access-%DATE%-%currentTime%.log
    for /f "skip=%retainCount% eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d access*.log') do @del "%%F"
)

REM check if the service is not running, start service
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "nginx" ^| findstr "STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (

   echo starting nginx service
   net start "nginx"   
  )
)

:DONE
popd
exit %ERRORLEVEL%
```